# python: change printing of class

Tags: python, mysql, class, object, printing

Is it possible in python to change what is printed for classes. I know that if we provide `__str__` `__unicode__` methods, we can change the way instances of a class are printed. But i want to do this for a class

Eg:

```
class A(object):
    def __str__(self):
        return 'hello'

a = A()
print a
```

will print `hello`. Is it possible to change the behaviour of `print A` which by default prints something like `<class '__main__.A'>`

**Update**: I guess i might as well explain the context. I am trying to create MySQL queries and i have classes representing tables. Each of these table-classes have a class variable containing the table name. So what i want to do is to be able to pass the Class as parameter to cursor.execute and have the tablenames substituted in the query.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, by providing a [metaclass](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation). This is a bad idea because metaclasses don't compose very well, and it's magical and confusing.

```
>>> class A(type):
...     def __repr__(self):
...             return '<this is not a class!>'
...
>>> class B(object):
...     __metaclass__ = A
...
>>> print B
<this is not a class!>
```

(you can change `__str__` as well, it depends on the semantics of what this is)

---

You updated your post to talk about generating SQL queries from a class. Instead of changing `str(Class)`, why not instead use `Class.__name__` (i.e. the name you defined it with), or perhaps `Class.table_name` (i.e. some class attribute you define for each class)? Being able to pass in classes and have them automagically work as table names that aren't of the form `<class 'foo.x'>` is potentially very confusing to future readers of your code, because it's not clear that this should work from context. The reader must remember that metaclass hacks were involved (a relatively rare thing, although not in ORMs!) and what the metaclass hack did. In contrast, just passing `Class.table_name` instead of `Class` makes it very obvious what is going on.

Comment: "metaclasses don't compose very well, and it's magical and confusing" can you elaborate a little

Comment: @zeem Re:composition, using two different metaclasses requires you to create one new metaclass that inherits from both of them, which might not work very well if they aren't meant to be inherited. As a general rule, classes, and especially metaclasses, aren't meant to be multiply inherited from, and this can and will blow up. Re: magical/confusing, the basic problem is that people expects `repr(SomeClass)` to look like the repr of a class, and if you alter it, that breaks this expectation. So people might see a class and not even *know* it's a class.

Answer (score 4):

Easy enough with a metaclass. A metaclass is to the class, what the class is to the instance

```
class A_meta(type):
    def __str__(cls):
        return 'foobar'


class A(object):
    __metaclass__ = A_meta
    def __str__(self):
        return 'hello'

a = A()
print a
print A
```